# Getting masked layer as UIImage on Swift on top of UIImageView

Tags: swift, image, image-processing, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to get the `UIImage` of the mask that I applied to a `UIImageView`.

I'm adding the mask using `UIBezierPath` and want the actual masked layer as `UIImage`, not the whole image. Think of it as a crop feature.

I'm cropping the image using:

```
func cropImage() {
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    viewSource.imageView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    viewSource.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewSource.imageView.bounds.size, false, 1)
    viewSource.imageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.completionObservable.onNext(newImage)
}
```

This eventually gives me the masked image on top of the old dimensions (the initial imageView width and height). But I want to have only the masked image, excluding the white background around them.

The screens are as shown:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well the code you presented did provide a transparent frame image. If you set the background of UIImageView in the bottom, you will know what I mean.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove that transparent frame of the image and just get the actual layered image

Comment: you cannot , a image has to be rectangular somehow.

Comment: you didn't understand it correctly @E.Coms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what you mean now. Here is the answer, just update the size of imageContext.

```
          UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((shapeLayer.path?.boundingBoxOfPath)!.size, false, 1)
```

If it's not so simple, can try CIImage pipeline to achieve.

```
    let context =  CIContext()
    let m1 = newImage?.cgImage
    let m = CIImage.init(cgImage: m1!)
    let bounds = imageView.layer.bounds
    let cgImage =   context.createCGImage(m, from: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: bounds.size.height, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height))
    let newUIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage!)
```

You may need to adjust transform.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've changed the code and it appears it doesnt crop the image correctly. https://imgur.com/a/gLaQAaH The yellow background is the imageView's backgroundColor.

Comment: I've just added `viewSource.imageView.image = newImage`

Comment: When I save the image, only the top left corner of the portion is saved. I think there is a positioning issue, since we're not getting the whole screen at the moment.

Comment: It's easy to move the picture and shape layer path to top-left? right?

Comment: Unfortunately not. And there is also auto layout which doesnt get affected after image crop action

Comment: This is another way you may try.